# XAudio2 and *.wav loading, HRESULT 0x88960001

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, xaudio2

I am trying to load a *.wav file that is a microsoft wav/8bit pcm file.  I am using the following code to load the data:

```
class WavFile : public AudioSource, public LoadableObject
{
public:
    WavFile( void )
        : AudioSource()
        , LoadableObject()
    { }

    virtual concurrency::task<void> Load( Platform::String^ path )
    {
        buffer = nullptr;

        BasicReaderWriter^ rw = ref new BasicReaderWriter();
        return rw->ReadDataAsync( path ).then([this, path]( const Platform::Array<byte>^ arr ){

            DWORD chunkId = 0, fileSize = 0, chunkSize = 0, extra = 0;

            ByteStream stream( arr );

            stream.ReadData( &chunkId, sizeof( chunkId ) );
            //chunkId = stream.ReadDWORD();
            char test[4];
            for(unsigned int i=0; i <4; i++)
                test[i] = ((char *)&chunkId)[i];
            if ( chunkId != 'FFIR' ) throw ref new Platform::FailureException( L"Could not get RIFF chunk in file " + path + L", chunkId=" + chunkId.ToString() );

            fileSize = stream.ReadDWORD();
            if ( fileSize <= 16 ) throw ref new Platform::FailureException( L"Wave file size is too small; " + path );

            extra = stream.ReadDWORD();
            for(unsigned int i=0; i <4; i++)
                test[i] = ((char *)&extra)[i];
            if ( extra != 'EVAW' ) throw ref new Platform::FailureException( L"Could not get WAVE chunk in file " + path + L", chunkId=" + chunkId.ToString() );

            bool formatChunk = false;
            for(unsigned int i = 12; i < fileSize; )
            {
                stream.Seek( i, true );
                chunkId = stream.ReadDWORD();
                stream.Seek( i + 4, true );
                chunkSize = stream.ReadDWORD();
                if ( chunkId = ' tmf' )
                {
                    stream.Seek( i + 8, true );
                    stream.ReadData( &waveFormat, sizeof( WAVEFORMATEX ) );
                    formatChunk = true;
                    break;
                }

                chunkSize += 8 + 1;
                chunkSize &= 0xfffffffe;
                stream.Seek( chunkSize, false );
                i += chunkSize;
            }
            if ( !formatChunk ) throw ref new Platform::FailureException( L"Could not get fmt chunk in file " + path );

            bool filledData = false;
            for(unsigned int j=12; j < fileSize; )
            {
                stream.Seek( j, true );
                chunkId = stream.ReadDWORD();
                for(unsigned int i=0; i <4; i++)
                    test[i] = ((char *)&chunkId)[i];
                stream.Seek( j + 4, true );
                chunkSize = stream.ReadDWORD();
                if ( chunkId == 'atad' )
                {
                    byte *bufferData = new byte[chunkSize];
                    stream.Seek( j + 8, true );
                    stream.ReadData( bufferData, chunkSize );
                    buffer = ref new Platform::Array<byte>( bufferData, (unsigned int)chunkSize );
                    delete bufferData;

                    xbuffer.AudioBytes = chunkSize;
                    xbuffer.pAudioData = buffer->Data;
                    xbuffer.PlayBegin = 0;
                    xbuffer.PlayLength = 0;

                    filledData = true;
                    break;
                }
                chunkSize += 8 + 1;
                chunkSize &= 0xfffffffe;
                j += chunkSize;
            }
            if ( !filledData ) throw ref new Platform::FailureException( L"Could not find data chunk in file " + path );

        });
    }
};
```

It parses the wav file properly, and here is what the WAVEFORMATEX data looks like:

`{ wFormatTag=1, nChannels=2, nSamplesPerSec=22050, nAvgBytesPerSec=44100, nBlockAlign=2, wBitsPerSample=8, cbSize=24932 }`

When I call `instance->CreateSourceVoice( &voice, wave->GetWaveFormat(), 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_FREQ_RATIO, reinterpret_cast<IXAudio2VoiceCallback*>( &voiceIn[id]->callbacks ) )`, I get HRESULT=0x88960001, where `instance` is of the type `IXAudio2*`, which I encompass in a class where it is statically shared in the class and initialized/destroyed with my class constructor/destructor:

```
AudioManager::AudioManager(void)
{
    instance_count++;
    if ( instance == nullptr )
    {
        DX::ThrowIfFailed( XAudio2Create( &instance, 0 ) );
    }
}


AudioManager::~AudioManager(void)
{
    /* Remove all the voices that were added in this audio manager */

    instance_count--;
    if ( instance_count == 0 )
    {
        HaltAudio();
        instance->Release();
        instance = nullptr;
    }
}
```

I have read in multiple places that this HRESULT is some sort of Windows 8 bug which has not been fixed for more than a year.  I can't accept that this is an ongoing bug and more inclined to think this is an issue with my code.  You can check out [my full implemention for XAudio2 in this gist](https://gist.github.com/mrozbarry/5060629).

Comment: That's XAUDIO2_E_INVALID_CALL, it doesn't like an argument value you passed.

Comment: Ah, so I wasn't creating a mastering voice first, which apparently needs to be in place.  I'm surprised there isn't a better HRESULT value to describe this situation.

Answer (score 1):

When setting the sendList of an XAudio2SourceVoice* to NULL, the IXAudio2 interface must have at least one mastering voice already set.