# IXAudio2Engine::CreateSourceVoice fails

Tags: c++, direct3d, xaudio2

I receive the Error `XAUDIO2_E_INVALID_CALL` when I try to call `IXAudio2Engine::CreateSourceVoice`. My code for creating a source voice is as follows:

```cpp
auto sample_rate = quality_to_sample_rate(settings.quality, sound_category::effect);
WAVEFORMATEX wave_format{ // 8000Hz 16 bit mono WAV
    .wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM,
    .nChannels = 1,
    .nSamplesPerSec = sample_rate,
    .nAvgBytesPerSec = sample_rate* 2,
    .wBitsPerSample = 16,
    .cbSize = 0,
};
XAUDIO2_SEND_DESCRIPTOR send_descriptor{.Flags = 0, .pOutputVoice = master_voice};
XAUDIO2_VOICE_SENDS sends{.SendCount = 1, .pSends = &send_descriptor};
res = sound_engine->CreateSourceVoice(&v, &wave_format, 0, 2.0f, nullptr, &sends);
if(FAILED(res)) {
    log_error("Could not create effect source voice with", sample_rate, "Hz");
    throw std::runtime_error("Could not create effect source voice");
}
log_debug("Created effect source voice with ", sample_rate, "Hz at ", (void*)v);
```

`master_voice` is not `nullptr` and is of type `IXAudio2MasteringVoice*` (i.e. `CreateMasteringVoice` returned `S_OK`!)

What am I missing?

Edit:

According to [XAudio2 and *.wav loading, HRESULT 0x88960001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146804/xaudio2-and-wav-loading-hresult-0x88960001) ,
it is possible to set `pSendList` to `NULL` which would result in using the MasteringVoice. but that does not help either.

Comment: Note you may want to take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Audio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the docs helps:

`nBlockAlign` and `nAvgBytesPerSecond` need to be set correctly.
`nBlockAlign` needs to be `(nChannels * (nBitsPerSample/8)) / 8` and
`nAvgBytesPerSecond` is `nBlockAlign * nSamplesPerSecond`